# External Content Type does not match the schema version for the form

Tags: sharepoint-designer, infopath, external-content-type

When I try to edit or view the item within the External List view the error message is as followed:

Error

InfoPath cannot open the form because of an application configuration error: The schema version for the External Content Type does not match the schema version for the form. To fix this problem, contact the form designer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a new List & Forms, but do not check 'Create InfoPath Form'. You can create a new custom form after creating the list.